Cannot go into the boot menu by holding option (alt) on Mac Mini A1347 that has Ubuntu Server 24 on it
I found a Mid 2011 Mac mini (i5-2520M) and decided to install Ubuntu Server 24 on it. Everything went perfectly and now I have the OS properly setup. However, some of the programs I want to run require a lower version of Ubuntu Server. I now want to flash Ubuntu 20 to the Mac mini.
The problem I am having is if I hold down the "alt" key on my keyboard (expecting that would correspond to "option"), the device turns on, but I have a blank screen. I followed this and tried other options and the only thing that made it behave different was "Option-Command-P-R: Reset NVRAM or PRAM.". If I try to reset NVRAM or PRAM, the machine keeps playing the Mac startup sound as I am holding the combination for more than 20 seconds and nothing happens - I keep seeing a blank screen.
I should point out the Ubuntu Server is perfectly healthy and if I don't hold any buttons on boot, I can boot into it perfectly.
What options do I have to get into the native boot screen on my Mac mini?

Sound like the EFI volume does not contain a /EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI file. This what the Mac Startup Manager would need to find in order to display an icon.

Hello, @DavidAnderson. Thank you for your comment.
I actually see something like you mention when I put in efibootmgr:
Boot0080*      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD/1,GPT,some-long-hash,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi) and the same long-string with BootFFFF*. Boot0000* Ubuntu corresponds to another line.


What model Mac Mini do you have? 2. When you say “blank screen” are you seeing the backlight of your display turn on, or no? 3. When in this state, does pressing Caps Lock toggle the caps lock light on your keyboard? 4. Is there another bootable device present on your machine when you try this, such as a flash drive containing a flashed macOS installer volume?


UtkuYücel: Have you created the Ubuntu Server 20 installer flash drive? If so, does this flash drive appear when you hold down the "alt" key at startup?

Hey @pion, thank you for your answer. 1. I have an A1347. 2. Display does not turn on. 3. Yes, it does turn it on/off. 4. The only usb connection is to the keyboard when I try this. Other ports are unused.

@DavidAnderson Yes, I have created one. And when I try to get into the boot screen, the screen does not turn on. I tried both the USB plugged/unplugged while holding "alt". I think it is helpful for me to point out that if I don't hold any keys the device boots into Ubuntu Server 24 with no problems.

I would think at this point that the problem is the keyboard. Either you have an Apple keyboard and both Alt keys are broken. (I assume you tried both keys individually.) Or, the non-Apple keyboard that is not compatible with your Mac. I have this happen with my 2007 iMac, where the Alt keys work when booted to an operating system (macOS, Linux, Windows, etc.) but not when booting the Mac.

Can you edit you question and add the output from the command cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Hz? This information can be used to determine the exact model year of your Mac.

Thanks to David Anderson's comment I found out that the problem was definitely with the keyboard! I used another keyboard and held the "alt" key and the boot screen showed up.
